# "javascript:" uri protocol replaces whole page with text

Tags: javascript, uri

So, I was trying to make a `javascript:` link with some code like `a="foo"`. I tried using `javascript:a="foo"` but it didn't work. Instead of changing the var `a` to `"foo"` it replaces the whole page with `foo` like `document.write` for some reason.

I also tried encoding the URI, but neither `javascript:a%3D%22foo%22` nor `javascript:%61%3D%22%66%6F%6F%22` work.

Since calling functions like `javascript:alert("Hello World!")` work, I ran `javascript:a=String("foo")`, without any luck either. Using `javascript:var%20a="foo"` does work, though, as well as `javascript:a=123`, but it won't work for me because my final goal is to change a property in an object.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Also, `javascript:a=String.fromCharCode(102,111,111)` does the exact same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting variables inline inside DOM attributes is not good practice, but if you have to:

```
<a href="javascript: void(a='foo')">Link</a>
```

or

```
<a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="a='foo'">Link</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was not using hyperlinks, but `void()` works.

Comment: Oh, I see. When the expression inside a `javascript:` protocol returns a string, it prints the string, but void always returns `undefined`. That's why `var` worked.